# Как организовать обновление данных в progressBar?

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

Пытаюсь организовать обновление полоски ProgressBar при обработке файла с прайс листом
Вот код на клиенте:

```
$('.import').on('beforeSubmit', function () {
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        $.fancybox({
            'scrolling'     : 'no',
            'overlayOpacity': 1,
            'closeBtn': false,
            'width': 628,
            'height': 208,
            'helpers' : {
              'overlay' : { 'closeClick': false}
            },
            'autoSize' : false,
            'content' : '<div class=\"progress-striped progress import-progress\" id=\"w0\"><div style=\"width:0%\" aria-valuemax=\"100\" aria-valuemin=\"0\" aria-valuenow=\"10\" role=\"progressbar\" class=\"progress-bar-info active progress-bar\"><span class=\"sr-only\">0% Complete</span></div></div><p class=\"progress-per\">Выполнено 0%</p><p class=\"progress-time\">Осталось 0 минут 0 секунд</p>'
        });
        setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
                url: '/admin/price/progress',
                method: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                headers: {Connection: close},
                mimeType:'multipart/form-data',
                contentType: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                complete: function(res) {
                    var im  = res;
                    var per = (im.row*100/im.totalRow);
                    var sec = 0;
                    console.log(im);
                    $('.progress-striped > div').css('width', per + '%');
                    $('.progress-per').text('Выполнено ' + per + '%');
                    sec++;
                    secEnd = 100 - per * sec;
                    $('.progress-time').text('Осталось ' + secEnd/60 + ' минут ' + secEnd%60 + ' секунд');
                },

            });
            return false;

        }, 1000 );
        $.ajax({
                url: $('form').attr('action'),
                method: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                mimeType:'multipart/form-data',
                contentType: false,
                complete: function(res) {
                    $.fancybox.close();
                },
            });
        return false;
    });
```

В экшине с обработкой прайса

```
<?php 
...
\Yii::$app->session->set('import', ['row' => $row, 'totalRow' => $highestRow]);
...
?>
```

В экшине с получением строки, на которой остановился скрипт

```
return json_encode(Yii::$app->session->get('import'));
```

Почему то запросы на /admin/price/progress виснут до тех пор, пока не выполнится /admin/price/import

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, где я ошибся?

Answer (score 1):

В PHP встроен так называемый блокирующий механизм сессий. Это значит, что пока одна сессия открыта в одном процессе, другие ее прочитать не могут. В случае, если причина в этом, то надо так или иначе подменить обработчик сессий, например, можно их писать в [базу данных](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-dbsession.html) (однако имейте в виду, что в этом случае могут иметь место типичные проблемы синхронного доступа - например, что в сессию пишутся данные более раннего запроса, который, однако, кончается позже второго).

Comment: Без обращения к сессии работает также некорректно. Боюсь что проблема "висящих" запросов не в этом.

Comment: @LANSELOT к ней необязательно обращаться, достаточно, чтобы фреймворк вызывал `session_start()`.

Comment: Убрал из кода чтение/запись из сессии, но не помогло..

Comment: @LANSELOT к ней необязательно обращаться, достаточно, чтобы ***фреймворк*** вызывал session_start().